# Как отобразить количество часов большее чем 24 в формате 472253:XX:XX?

Tags: javascript

Этот код на JS

`new Date(1700113910366).toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit', timeZone: 'UTC'})`

показывает 05:XX:XX, а должен показывать 472253:XX:XX. Как этого достичь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> показывает 05:XX:XX, а должен показывать 472253:XX:XX. Как этого достичь?

Например вот так...

```js
const v = 1700113910366
const d = new Date(v)
let t = d.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit', timeZone: 'UTC'})
t = t.split(':')
t[0] = Math.trunc(v / 1000 / 60 / 60)
t = t.join(':')
console.log(t)
```

Comment: 1. Можно не указывать `hour: '2-digit'`, чтобы потом не отрезать, 2. `/ 1000 / 60 / 60 == /36e5`